# Execute jQuery function if input value is correct

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple overlay which will disappear if an input field is correct. A super basic login page if you will, which is a div containing an input. My understanding of jQuery is limited so I've no doubt my syntax is a mess.

```
<div id="enter">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="password" required>
</div>

if $("input[name= "est1889"]").change(function() {
    $("#enter").fadeOut("slow");
};
```

Comment: Are waiting for the `document` to load?

`$(document).ready(function() {
    // your JavaScript
});`

Comment: Use `$('#password')` instead of `$("input[name= "est1889"]")`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems pretty out of wack.

First, make sure you are wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function()...` like @Teodor Kurev mentioned.

Your `if` block is out of place, and isn't valid syntax. You probably want to bind the `input` event for your textbox, and then check the value inside of that.

I'm also assuming `est1889` is the value you're trying to check, but it's hard to tell from your question. The selector for your input should actually just be `#password`

Full example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#password').on('input', function() {
    console.log('input');
    if ($(this).val() === 'est1889') {
      // Correct here
      console.log('correct');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="enter">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="password" required>
</div>
```